# JSON interaction after OAuth2/OmniAuth authentication

Tags: ruby, json, twitter, sinatra, omniauth

Context: I'm trying to interact with Twitter via JSON and no libraries as i'm practicing to interact with a newly released receipt printer(themprinter.com) which has no helper libraries. I need to OAuth with the printer then make the appropriate calls to register my device, print, verify online/offline status etc.

I've successfully authenticated with Twitter via OmniAuth's Twitter Gem. I can pull all the data from the Authentication Hash here - https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter

...now what? I want to be able to make a JSON call with my OAuth credentials to Twitter and pull my timeline or any other such data. Can anyone provide any sample code that will allow me a starting point to tinker with and work off of?

Answer (score 1):

```
Twitter provides REST API. Here's how you might create a GET REST request

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url, initheader = header)
http_request = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
response = http_request.start {|http| http.request(request)}

here's an example of the request URL:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```

Comment: This is a great start, thank you. But this is for basic authentication, with Twitter's v1.1 of their API, every request needs to be signed with the token and secret. How do I add that into this GET request?